# I am facing issue while executing JSONRenderer.render(serialized_student_data.data) in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

*I am new to Django, Whenever i execute the line json_data = JSONRenderer.render(serialized_student_data.data) it gives me error like **TypeError: render() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'***

**#Here is code in the models.py**

```
class StudentModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='user')
    roll_no = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Ahmedabad')
```

**#Here is code in the serializers.py**

```
class StudentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    roll_no = serializers.IntegerField()
    city = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
```

**#Here is code in the views.py**

```
def student_view(request):
    student_object = StudentModel.objects.get(id=3)
    serialized_student_data = StudentSerializer(student_object)
    json_data = JSONRenderer.render(serialized_student_data.data)
    return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: You should use `@renderer_classes([JSONRenderer])` on your function based views and `return Response(serialized_student_data)`

Comment: You passed a Serializer instance as data, but probably meant to pass serialized `.data` or `.error`. representation. It is showing this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create JSONRender object instead of use class, and the code will  be,

```
    json_data = JSONRenderer().render(data=serialized_student_data.data)
```

Comment: I have used that earlier but it throws error like this render() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: Please ensure that you have put parentheses() after JSONRenderer. Or just copy and paste this line to your editor then check.

Answer (score 0):

```
create a separate render file in the same app you are working on.
code of a renderer will  work for all the views you are using add the 
renderer class where you want to use 

from rest_framework import renderers
import json

class StudentRenderer(renderers.JSONRenderer):
  charset='utf-8'
  def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
    response = ''
    if 'ErrorDetail' in str(data):
      response = json.dumps({'errors':data})
    else:
      response = json.dumps(data)
    
    return response


then add the render class into the student view class 

first import the respective library.
from user.renderers import StudentRenderer

use this in the student view anywhere 
renderer_classes = [StudentRenderer]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).